# Trying to convert a 2 digit year to a 4 digit year using strftime()

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a 2 digit year to a 4 digit year using this command:

```
df['year'] = df['year'].strftime('%Y')
```

this is the error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'

I get, not sure why its not working I have used this command many times before.

here is my sample data
[image]

and here is my desired output:
[image]

Comment: You need to be referring to a specific row not the entire `year` series.

Comment: After a short look at the docs you would see it is "df['year'].dt.strftime('%Y')"

Comment: [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) possibly

Comment: What are the rules? Can't you just add `'19'` (or `1900` if integers)?

Comment: "50" is not a date/time value.  It's never going to have a `strftime` member.  And two-digit years less than 70 are interpreted as 21st Century, so you'd get 2050, not 1950.  You need to manipulate this as an integer first.